# Use ASP.NET WEB FORMS Server Side

Tags: asp.net, webforms

we're trying to "interact" with an old webapp using **ASP.NET Web Forms** from within our backend code.

We're basically chaining a few POST calls over to this ASP.NET part and then parsing the HTML we get back.

We're having troubles with this **__VIEWSTATE** hidden input (looks like for each POST/page change it changes). 
Also after the initial GET we make to the page, we're saving the cookie we get back and use it for all the other POSTs.

Anybody ever had to do something like this?
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Since you parse the HTML you get back, you can retrieve the new ViewState value and use that one for the next PostBack.

Comment: yeah. we do that. it should be enough, right? still i'd like to check out the logic behind viewstate "production", so to speak

Comment: I guess that would be enough. What error do you get?

Comment: some silly conversion error. like we're not sending a number parameter at all or we're sending it as an empty string or something. when i use the form on my browser it works. i've checked all the params and tested my server side version with exactly the same ones and get the erro.